# Change url to article in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-3.x

I create a new website. In the old one I had the url to an article like:

```
www.mysite.com/article,{article_id},{article_title}.html
```

I want to change the structure of my url in cakephp without losing my SEO position in google. How can I do it ?

I use Cakephp 3.8
I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an apache webserver, I'd set `301 redirects` in the htaccess to tell the robot the old URLs are `moved permanentely`.

**This shouldn't affect SEO as it is a standard procedure.**

Depending on how your new URL format looks like, you can then use a query-string for dynamic urls like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^article,.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?article,$2 [L,QSA]
```